# Web app in Android Webview has inconsistent navigation with soft keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, ember.js, webview, webkit

I have a web app written in **EmberJS** accessed on an Android device by means of a app that's essentially just a web view.  The app targets Android 4.1/API level 16 and we're constrained to this.

Occasionally when using the "next" and "prev" keys on the soft keyboard to navigate between fields the soft keyboard will close and will not re-open on the next field.  We most often see this issue when moving focus from a text field to a select field where the soft keyboard should be replaced with the select dialog, however it has been seen simply moving from text field to text field.

How can I correct this behaviour and make it so the soft keyboard/select dialog appears consistently?  Here's the list of things I've already attempted based on other stack overflow/development blogs I have found.

Added an on touch listener to focus on the web view.  This has no noticeable effect.

```
browser.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) { 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 

                if (!v.hasFocus()) { 
                    v.requestFocus(); 
                } 

                break; 
            } 

        return false; 

        }
    });
```

I added the following to **AndroidManifest.xml** however it just caused the view port not to move to the field that has focus.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

I wrote an interface method that can be called directly from JavaScript that attempts to show the soft input keyboard.  Our testers have said this has improved reliability in general, but we still have issues going between select dropdowns and text input fields.

**Java**

```
public void showSoftKeyboard() {                
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    imm.showSoftInput(browser, 0);
}
```

**JavaScript/Ember**

```
if (window.jsinterface) {
    window.jsinterface.showSoftKeyboard();
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

**Update**

Some additional information that'd probably be useful, plus tried to make the issue a bit clearer.

Our clients are using the Galaxy Note II as their device of choice running on Android 4.1.  Our app uses API level 16 so we are tied down to the old Webkit Web View as opposed to the Chromium implementation pushed out in 4.4/API level 19.